Access is denied error when running flutter start on visual studio
I installed Flutter to my pc today and by command "Flutter Create" it created Flutter files successfully, but when I open these files from Visual Studio and trying to run my Flutter project on Windows using the command Flutter run, but I'm getting an Access is denied error for flutter.bat. Here’s the full error message:
Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ flutter run
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter start
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Does anyone know what might be causing this or any steps I can try to resolve it?

can you include flutter doctor -v

sorry, sir my pc got crashed, I bought a new computer yesterday. Flutter runs fine in that device, thank you
